# How to remove constraints on the number of arguments when mocking with Spock?

Tags: java, mocking, spock

Is there a way to accept any number of arguments when mocking a method?

For instance if I want to mock those 2 methods:

```
foo(String s);
foo(String s, int i);
```

For now, in my test I do:

```
myMockedClass.foo(_) >> x
myMockedClass.foo(_, _) >> x
```

Is there a way to mock both at once? Something like:

```
myMockedClass.foo(*) >> x
```

(this doesn't work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is planned, but doesn't exist yet. The proposed syntax is `foo.bar(*_)`.

Comment: Already implemented in the latest snapshot. `*_` stands for "any number (including zero) of additional arguments". It must come at the end (but not necessarily at the start) of the argument list.